# Когда прописываю background-attachment: fixed;то картинка исчезает, увеличиваю значение Max-width-все ок. Что делать, как решить без увеличения with

Tags: css, html5

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

.content {

```
max-width: 1200px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 30px auto;
```

}

.content__header {

```
background: url(./img/HTML5.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 150px 150px;
background-position: top 35px right;
/* background-attachment: fixed; */
```

}

.content-block {

```
width: 800px;
border: 1px solid black;
```

}

Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно из-за `background-position: top 35px right;` у вас картина уходит в право за рамки просто, попробуйте `background-position: top 35px right (введите нужный вам пиксель)px;` должно получится https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment там есть встроенный редактор можете потренироваться